# FireStore and maps/arrays, document-list to array in Kotlin

Tags: arrays, firebase, dictionary, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I've finally started to understand a lot of info regarding FireStore, but I'm wondering if I can get some assistance.

If I had a setup similar to or like this:

races

Android

name: Android

size: medium

stats          <---- this is the map

str: 10

sex: 12.... (more values)

How would I parse this? I am looking to make specific TextViews apply values found in the database so that I can simply update the database and my app will populate those values so that hard coding and code updating won't be nearly as troublesome in the future.

I currently use something like this:

```
val androidRef = db.collection("races").document("Android") 
androidRef.get().addOnSuccessListener { document ->
if (document != null) {
     oneOfTheTextViews.text = document.getString("str") 
} else { 
}
```

The issue is currently I can only seem to access from collection (races) / document (android) / then a single field (I have "str" set as a single field, not part of a map or array)

What would the best practice be to do this? Should I not nest them at all? And if I can reference said nesting/mapping/array, what functions need to be called? (To be clear, I am not asking only whether or not it is possible - the reference guides and documents allude to such - but what property/class/method/etc needs to be called in order to access only one of those values or point to one of those values?).

Second question: Is there a way to get a list of document names? If I have several races, and simply want to make a spinner or recycler view based on document names as part of a collection, can I read that to the app?

Comment: It is better to create new node. Separate the `stats` from the node `races`

Comment: So races is the collection, and Android is the document. You're suggesting make stats its own collection, or document? Each document will only possess perhaps 10~20 fields, if that (that's actually on the larger end).

Comment: I suggest to make stats out from the races nodes.

Comment: Is there an answer to my second question? Making documents in a collection into an array to use for a spinner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What would the best practice be to do this?

If you want to get the value of your `str` property which is nested within your `stats` map, please change the following line of code:

```
oneOfTheTextViews.text = document.getString("str")
```

to

```
oneOfTheTextViews.text = document.getString("stats.str")
```

If your `str` property is a number and **not** a String, then instead of the above line of code please use this one:

```
oneOfTheTextViews.text = document.getLong("stats.str")
```

> Should I not nest them at all?

No, you can nest as many properties as you want within a `Map`.

> Is there a way to get a list of document names?

Yes, simply iterate the collection and get the document ids using `getId()` function.